# Android dropdown using Gingerbread

Tags: android

I want to create a dropdown(not a spinner) using gingerbread.

I thought of using a dialog box without buttons.But since its a list i dont think that would be possible. Moreover each item should be clickable.

It should be more like dropdowns in websites.

To get the dialog box i have used.Basically i am moving the position of the dialog box from the center to any specified position. How do i get a list in this dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [QuickAction](https://github.com/evancharlton/quick-actions-demo/tree/master/app) is available.

Starting in Android 2.0 (API level 5), Android debuted the concept of "quick actions" in the platform. This UI pattern is the idea that tapping an object could reveal extra information in an anchored pop-up way. This could expose additional functionality to the user in a uniform and uncluttered way.

The final product will look like this:

[image]

Hope this may helps you :)